# How to assign conditional value on twig object

Tags: php, twig

I have a following code and I want to be able to assign value of count conditionally.

```
{% set obj = {
 count: CONDITIONAL VALUE,
 city: 'London',
 country: 'UK'
} %}
```

I have an object with many properties, I need to check if that object has property counter . If it has I want to assign value of counter to count above else I want to pass 2 as default value to count.
In `javascript` i could do:-  count: `counter || 2`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a default value for a non-existing or `null` variable u'd use the filter [default](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.htmlhttps://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html)

```
{% set obj = {
 count: my_value|default(2),
 city: 'London',
 country: 'UK'
} %}


{{ obj.count }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/fjjbli)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Happy new year.